# MongoDB Queries - Data Filtration

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have a data filter form which contains around **15 to 20** dropdown fields.The purpose of the dropdown fields is to provide data filtration options. For example look at the image below (*the image is from the Zoopla App*):

[image]

As you can see in the image that it shows 7 dropdown fields. The User picks an option for each field or only a few fields and taps on search button and the result is shown.

**I am trying to achieve the same functionality but theres an issue.**

**What I have tried so far!**

The user has the option to whether fill all the dropdown fields or maybe just 2 and still be able to search. The search functionality is very fluid. The user can only select **ONE** dropdown field and leave all the rest empty and still be able to get the result.

To implement this I created the following route in my API.

```
app.get('/user/test',function(req, res) {

 User.find({"$or": [{"employeeName": req.body.employeeName}, {"sector": {$elemMatch:{sec: req.body.sec}}} ] }, function(err, user) 
 {
     if (err)
       {
         res.send(err);
       }
        console.log(user);
        res.json(user);

   });
   });
```

As you can see I am using the **$or** to get the data back.The issue is that If the user only fills out both the employeeName and sector parameters and searches it sends back all the data that matches either employeeName or matches sector. In reality I only want the data that matches both parameters inclusive. Then I tried using the **$and** which fixed the problem but now the user can't search just for a single parameter like employeeName or just sector. It has to have both parameters present to be able return the data.

To summarise how can I edit my search route in my API to give user the flexibility of searching in any way and with any number of parameters. Just to be clear the search will only take place within the dropdown fields on the page. So if there are 20 dropdown fields then the user has possibility of being able to ***search with a minimum of 1 parameter and a maximum of 20 parameters***

**It is a little difficult for me to get my point across so if you don't understand the question please let me know and I'll try to explain again**

Comment: build a query builder that will be a better option

Comment: @SarathNair thanks for the reply. could you explain a bit more? or maybe if you any resources? I am not sure what you mean by query builder.

Comment: Basically you need to test which parameters are given and then either build the queries accordingly or (not sure if this was a proper choice here as per the shere number of possibilities) select from a set of predefined queries. A query builder is basically an interface for an Query object where each of the methods returns the query object, so that you can append criteria dynamically. I'd show you how to do it, by my JS is horrible.

Comment: @MarkusWMahlberg Thank you for the comment. Would you have any online resources available? The concept of query building is quite new to me. What I understand is that to create a query for every possible search criteria within those 20 parameters and based on the users selection of the parameters run the predefined query. Is this correct?

Comment: No, the predefined queries were the other (probably unfitting solution). The predefined queries have nothing to do with the builder mentioned. I can link Java resources. Actually, the [wikipedia article on the Builder pattern has a good java example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern#Java_Example), which should be easy enough to understand even when you don't speak Java too well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can give you an example of how I build queries. I use this in many small services in a SOA project. Usually I check in a controller that params are validated according to the types I am waiting for (if you don't use orm's like Mongoose), then I build the query in the model.
Anyway, I hope this will help you.

```
app.get('/user/test',function(req, res) {
    // You initialize your mongodb query 
    var query = {};

    // If employeeName was set, then you update the query
    if (req.body.employeeName){
        query.employeeName = req.body.employeeName;
    }

    // Same for the sector
    if (req.body.sec){
        query.sector = {$elemMatch:{sec: req.body.sec};
    }
    // and you keep going for every paramaters...
    // Then you find with the query, if no parameter query = {}
    User.find(query, function(err, users){
        if (err){
            res.send(err);
        }
        console.log(users);
        res.json(users);
    });
});
```

I also see that you want to sort the results, so you will probably need to use [aggregate](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/) queries to handle this properly.
And for the "most recents" you can use the _id embeded timestamp :

```
ObjectId("564afd0b65d680ff47ccfc59").getTimestamp();
// =>ISODate("2015-11-17T10:10:19Z")

//And in a shorter way: 
db.collection.find(query).sort({_id:-1})

//Inside an aggregate it gives:
[{$sort: {_id: -1}}]
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer. It really does help. I'll implement it now and check. I just have one question though, by using your approach if the user sends a http call with 5 parameters or more would it still check all 5 parameters and return a result that matches all 5 parameters query? Or can it only handle one parameter at a time?

Comment: You have to code the checks by yourself, and you need to set the query that goes with if you receive this parameter.

In the above example, I treat only 2 parameters (employeeName and sec).
If you want to treat price, you ll have to check if the parameter exists first in the request(req.body.price), then you need to update your query according to what you want to do with this parameter.